# Use member function as function pointer

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I've never used function pointers before and I'm having some trouble getting my code to work. This is what I have

TestClass.h:

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        void function1();
        void function2();

        void function3(void (*funcPtr)(void))
        void function4();
};
```

TestClass.cpp

```
void TestClass::function1()
{
    //CODE
}

void TestClass::function2()
{
    //CODE
}

void TestClass::function3(void (*funcPtr)(void))
{
    //CODE
    funcPtr();
    //CODE
}

void TestClass::function4()
{
    function3(function1);
    function3(function2);
}
```

This give me the error

> "nonstandard form for taking the address of a member function

I tried to add TestClass:: infront of the *funcPtr but that gives me even more errors

Comment: Non-static member functions aren't functions - you cannot *call* a member function. Instead, you have to invoke it on an *object*.

Comment: You want: `void f(TestClass * obj, void (TestClass::* mf)()) { (obj->*mf)(); }` and call it like `f(this, &TestClass::function1)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With member function pointer, it should be something like:

```
void TestClass::function3(void (TestClass::*funcPtr)())
{
    //CODE
    (this->*funcPtr)();
    //CODE
}

void TestClass::function4();
{
    function3(&TestClass::function1);
    function3(&TestClass::function2);
}
```

With function pointer

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        static void function1(); // static added
        static void function2(); // static added

        void function3(void (*funcPtr)(void))
        void function4();
};

void TestClass::function3(void (*funcPtr)())
{
    //CODE
    funcPtr();
    //CODE
}

void TestClass::function4();
{
    function3(&TestClass::function1);
    function3(&TestClass::function2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use std::bind and std::function, which provide a better readability and more checking for you

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

```
#include <functional>

void TestClass::function3( std::function<void (void)> funcPtr )
{
    //CODE
    funcPtr();
    //CODE
}

void TestClass::function4()
{
    function3( std::bind(&TestClass::function1, this) );
    function3( std::bind(&TestClass::function2, this) );
}
```

Comment: Currently working with embedded systems and don't have access to the newer versions of c++